# Error while rendering D3 pie chart (not displaying properly)

Tags: ember.js, d3.js

I have a weird issue using Ember 1.11 (built with ember-cli) and [D3 Pie chart](http://d3pie.org/). 
The chart is not displayed properly on ember routes, only on the index route (index.hbs).

The generated HTML code is the same on routes templates and index.hbs. I've used the same view/component on index.hbs as on routes.

Weirdly enough, I can fix this issue if by going to Inspect Element and removing the entire `<head></head>` tag. (Removing the content line by line does not fix it!)

I've installed a sample Ember application [here.](http://weird.ember.socketo.com/) On the index you will see the chart. On the menu routes, there is the same chart (rendered with same view as it was rendered on index.hbs), but not displayed properly (it works a bit when you hover over that area).

The HTML code generated by the chart view is the same on all pages. If you copy the code from `<div id="pieChart">..</div>` and paste it in a empty static html page, the chart will be rendered correctly.

This issue can be reproduced using: Firefox/Chrome. In safari it seems to work.

[Here](http://paste2.org/C2ZDK7n3) is a paste2 which renders the chart.

The entire application code before build can be found [here](http://weird.ember.socketo.com/d3app.zip).

Edit: I've also reported this issue on github, [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10923).

Comment: could you reproduce your issue in jsbin? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/

Comment: No. it seems that cannot be reproduced on jsbin. Here is the code: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tinelibace/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `ENV.locationType` to "hash" instead of the default ("auto"). Since you're working with an ember-cli application, this lives in `config/environment.js`.

The ultimate culprit for this can be found here: https://github.com/benkeen/d3pie/blob/master/d3pie-source/_segments.js#L44. Basically, d3pie is using a pattern fill for the circle arcs, which is exposed as a URL. When you're inside a route, that ends up having to go through Ember, which is configured by default to ignore hashed routes. By switching it, you effectively take that call out of Ember's routing namespace and it's able to resolve correctly.

#### Edit

See here for a working example: https://github.com/Little-Jon/so-29780096

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Could you explain technically what happens with this setting?

Comment: Sure. That setting changes the `location` api implementation used in your application from the current default (`HistoryLocation`, which uses the browser API with the same name) to `HashLocation`, which reacts to `hashchange` events fired by Ember (I think - might be fired by the browser) on route changes (see http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Location.html#toc_hashlocation for more detailed documentation).